# Para que sirven las variables wrappers

Tags: java

¿En que tipo de circunstancias se pueden aplicar?

Ejemplo:

```
// Inicializar Primitivos 
int  i1 = 12; 
    int  i2 = 300;
long l1 = 200L; // sufijo para primitivo long
long l2 = 200l; // sufijo para primitivo long
long l3 = 200;
float f1 = 1e-39F; // sufijo para primitivo float
float f2 = 1e+11f; // sufijo para primitivo float
float f3 = 1;
double d1 = 32e46d; // sufijo para primitivo double
double d2 = 14D; // sufijo para primitivo double
double d3 = 1; 

// Inicializar "Wrappers" con primitivos
Integer wi1 = new Integer(i1);
Long wl1 = new Long(l1);
Float wf1 = new Float(f1);
Double wd1 = new Double(d1);
```

¿y por qué?

¡Gracias!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Principalmente hay dos motivos:

- Los tipos primitivos no son objetos, por tanto

  - no extienden `Object`:

    ```
    private output( Object o) { ...} //admite cualquier cosa menos un tipo primitivo
    ```
  - no se pueden usar con genéricos:

    ```
    List<Integer> lista= ... //válido
    List<int> lista= ... //error
    ```
- A veces puedes querer querer que tu modelo en Java sea *nullable*: Cuando guardas en bases de datos valores, no es lo mismo guardar `0` que guardar `null`.

Dicho esto, desde Java 5 (2004?) el lenguaje soporta *boxing/unboxing*:

```
 Integer i = 5; //los tipos primitivos se transforman en objetos automáticamente

 listaInteger.add(50); //compila perfectamente
 int num = listaInteger.get(0); //cuidado con los NPE!
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!!